# Create Map in Company of Heroes Tales of Valor

Tags: company-of-heroes

Company of Heroes Tales of Valor has 'world builder' in its folder but its very confusing!
Does world builder have any training or tutorial?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is some youtube videos to get you started that are helpful.

[Company of Heroes Tales of Valor Introduction to World Builder](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yi76rJAnAsY)

There is also the forums where you can see guides.

[Company of heroes Tales of Valor World Builder Guide](http://www.gamereplays.org/community/index.php?s=296ff611d9445f514a68b13550ad089e&showtopic=177413)

Comment: Tnx For Your Help :D

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old thread, but I am still making maps in 2021. I created some tutorials on how to do it.

[Here's a playlist of my tutorials](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d8UGE7yF9DE&list=PLNjrl9hRn-681Q8cdrupwnRFpuTN0Cd13)